# How can I get onClick/onLongClick events to work for a VideoView?

Tags: android

I have a VideoView which I want to call a method on of `fooMethod(VideoView vv)` whenever it's shortclicked, but show/hide the video controls if it's longclicked. However, VideoView doesn't seem to have the OnClick or OnLongClick events.

I've implemented the onTouchListener, but I can only seem to get DOWN and UP events from that; there doesn't seem to be support for detecting the length of a click.

Is there a good way to differentiate long and short clicks in the onTouchListener?

Comment: you could do this by yourself, when touching down save current milliseconds into a variable, and on touching up calculate the difference between now (current milliseconds) and the variable you had in touch down.

Comment: What about multitouch devices? And where do I put that variable? Global to the Activity? Static to the method? Thanks

Comment: I think you can disable multitouch if that's what you want. And also, you can save it as an instance variable for your whole activity if you like, it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit old, but could help anyone in the future with the same problem.

Looks like VideoView consumes the onClick/onLongClick for other features (didn't research it deep enough), so the other way is to do it manually with GestureDetectorCompat(compat, so it works with older versions).

**GestureDetectorCompat**

```
GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat =  new GestureDetectorCompat(context, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
              /* Always return true, to indicate that the gestureDetectorCompat
               * consumed the touch and can continue to the  
               * next gestures(long, single, etc..)
               */
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.i("SOME_TAG", "Longpress detected");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Your view which you want to implement the onClick/onLongClick.

**View**

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // Return the result from GestureDetectorCompat so the view
            // knows if the touch was consumes or not
            return gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<uses-features android:name="multi-touch" />
```

In your Manifest.xml